# When we initialize the data type char* and when not?

Tags: c++, variable-initialization

Firstly, look at the following simple code:

```
char str[80] = "This is - my text - for test";
const char s[2] = "-";
char *token;
token = strtok(str, s);

while (token != NULL) {
    printf(" %s\n", token);   
    token = strtok(NULL, s);
}
```

The function `strtok()` returns the data type `char*` and as you seen we created a variable named `token` that variable not initialized.

Now, look at the next code:

```
char *buff;
int num = 500;
sprintf(buff, "%d", num);
```

The result of the previous code is an error `uninitialized local variable 'buff'`.
My question is, why in the first code does not occurs any problem, while, in the second code occurred an error ?

Comment: `char* token = strtok(str, s);`

Comment: @PeteBecker: That is for direct assignment.

Comment: That is **initialization**. The original code creates `token` uninitialized, then **assigns** to it. For simple types like `int` and pointers the difference sometimes doesn't matter technically (provided you do the assignment right after creating the uninitialized variable), although the chance for mistakes is much higher. But for types whose constructors do significant work there's a big difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because in the first snippet you *do* initialize the variable `token`, by calling `strtok` and assigning the result of the call to the variable.

In the second example you leave the variable `buff` uninitialized.

You can initialize a local variable with an actual initialization at definition. *Or* by assigning to the variable elsewhere. The important thing is that you do this initialization or assignment *before* you use the variable in any other way.

Comment: Is this `sprintf(buff....` considered as assignment or considered as usage.

Comment: @LionKing The `sprintf`  function writes to the memory ***pointed to*** by the first argument. It does not modify the actual pointer. It's definitely usage. If you are unsure, *always* initialize variable some way.

Comment: @LionKing `sprintf(buff...` makes a *copy* of `buff` (as a parameter) but `buff` has not been given a value.